# Creating timed events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply creating a Simon Says-style light game, where the user must remember, in order, the colors that have lit up. I have a vector of colors (`colorArray`) that the code needs to go through. Each color will be set to a slightly different tone, and then will be reset before going on to the next color. However, all of the colors in the array are lit up at once (at least from a human perspective). It seems as if it's ignoring my `setTimeout` functions and running straight through all the code! I just cannot figure it out. As you can see below, I even added a parameter, `time`, that is incremented. However, this does not even solve the problem. You can see what its doing here: http://jsbin.com/qibik/9

```
var displayColors = function(colorArray,num,time)
{ 
  if(num!=colorArray.length)
    {
      setTimeout(setColor(colorArray,num),time);
      setTimeout(resetColors,time+400);
      num++;
      time+=10000;
      displayColors(colorArray,num,time);
    }
};

var setColor = function(colorArray,num)
{
      switch(colorArray[num])
        {

          case '#b':
            $('#b').css("background-color","#6367db");
            break;
          case '#g':
            $('#g').css("background-color","#14b826");
            break;
          case '#y':
            $('#y').css("background-color","#ebec85");
            break;
          case '#r':
            $('#r').css("background-color","#ee5c5c");
            break;       
        } 
};
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you're calling the function immediately, and passing its returned value to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(setColor(colorArray,num),time);
```

To create a timeout on a function with parameters, you'll need to create a closure:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setColor(colorArray, num);
}, time);
```

Comment: Ok I changed that but now its as if its not calling on setColor at all. Perhaps does resetColors in setTimeout(resetColors,time+400) get called immediately as well?

Comment: If you pass the name of a function to `setTimeout`, it won't be invoked until the timeout is reached.  It's only if you add the parentheses to turn it into a function call that it's invoked immediately.